# Added new nodes to cassandra cluster and data is missing

Tags: cassandra

I have added new 4 nodes to existing 4 nodes cluster. Now some data are missing on cluster. 
What can be the reason for it? what can I do for resolve it?

Data missing keyspace RF is 1 when I was adding to the cluster. It can be a issue?

Note: Once I added new nodes to cluster executed repair command to all nodes

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be running a RF of 1.

I imagine that if you added them all in a short timeframe with a low RF that the VNodes got shuffled from one node to another without settling.  I'm suprised a full repair didn't do anything.

You might check the HDDs of the original nodes to see if the repair didn't delete the old data.  If it's still there you may be able to remove the new nodes (temporarily) and then add each node back in 1 by 1 while repairing.

Edit: additionally probably use an odd number of nodes.

Comment: Highstead here I added new nodes to cluster 1 node in a 1 day. And alsomissing mean data is disappear from whole cluster.(Note: Still old nodes and new nodes are in same cluster)

Comment: So probably a bad idea.  The data for your cassandra cluster by default is stored in /var/lib/cassandra.  If the older files PREDATE when you added the nodes to the cluster you may be able to remove the new nodes one at a time.  And then when the data is settled remove the next.  

By the end of the process the nodes that own the data that is 'lost' would be the same nodes due to how consistant hashing works in cassandra.

Obviously, snapshot all your nodes first.  If this is a production system this may not be an option.  Also, check for snapshots on your nodes.